# RxSwift sequential flatMap with Moya request

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex, moya

I currently have the following code

```
func updateItems(_ observable: Observable<ContainingEntity>) -> Observable<ContainingEntity>{
    return observable
        .concatMap({ (containingEntity) -> Observable<ContainingEntity> in
            guard let itemEntity = orderEntity.itemEntity,
                itemEntity.name.count == 0 else{
                    return Observable.just(entity)
            }

            print("Need to fetch name of item #\(itemEntity.id)")

            return RestManager.getDetailOf(item: itemEntity)
                .flatMap({ (updatedItemEntity) -> Observable<ContainingEntity> in
                    var updatedContainingEntity = containingEntity
                    containingEntity.itemEntity = updatedItemEntity
                    print("Fetched item name: \(itemEntity.name)")
                    return Observable.just(containingEntity)
                })
        })
}
```

Basically, I need to make sure that the **itemEntity** of each **ContainingEntity** has a name and, if not, request it with Moya.

But I'm facing the following type of output from the two prints:

- Need to fetch name of item #1
- Need to fetch name of item #2
- Need to fetch name of item #3
- Fetched item name: Name1
- Fetched item name: Name2
- Fetched item name: Name3

Meaning that operations in my concatMap are executed in parallel, which I don't want because of requests redundancies and some cache system I didn't show here: I can have 30 times the same item id and I don't want to request it 30 times.

What I'm expecting is:

- Need to fetch name of item #1
- Fetched item name: Name1
- Need to fetch name of item #2
- Fetched item name: Name2
- Need to fetch name of item #3
- Fetched item name: Name3

How can I fix this issue? Thank you very much for your help.

**UPDATE:**

I'm now using some kind of simple buffer, which saves **ItemEntities** needing to be updated and assigns these items to the next **ContainingEntities** with the same item identifier. This prevents Moya from performing the same request several times.

It works perfectly but I don't very much like the idea of this mechanism external to RX...

Answer (score 1):

I think using a `Variable` or `BehaviorSubject` to control the sequential loading could work (code below).

*However* you might want to rethink the loading architecture, because by using this code, your loading times might be sub-optimal.

The concern of limiting how many simultaneous parallel requests are in-flight might belong to other component, like your networking layer.

I didn't test the code below, so it might not even compile  - if it works, please let me know and accept the answer.

```
func updateItems(_ observable: Observable<ContainingEntity>) -> Observable<ContainingEntity>{
  let trigger = BehaviorSubject<Int>(value: 0)
  let sequential = Observable.zip(observable, trigger) { return $0.0 }
  return sequential
    .concatMap({ (containingEntity) -> Observable<ContainingEntity> in
      guard let itemEntity = orderEntity.itemEntity,
        itemEntity.name.count == 0 else{
          return Observable.just(entity)
      }

      print("Need to fetch name of item #\(itemEntity.id)")

      return RestManager.getDetailOf(item: itemEntity)
        .flatMap({ (updatedItemEntity) -> Observable<ContainingEntity> in
          var updatedContainingEntity = containingEntity
          containingEntity.itemEntity = updatedItemEntity
          print("Fetched item name: \(itemEntity.name)")
          trigger.onNext(0)
          return Observable.just(containingEntity)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very interesting answer. But I actually tried this and not only is it a bit disappointing to use such a complex mechanism (because I have the same problem in 5 managers in my app), but it also  deadlocks if the Observable<ContainingEntity> is empty!

Comment: Makes sense @y00rn - I see the update to your question, about using a buffer.